# Как выйти на перебор определенного блока элементов массива foreach php

Tags: php, foreach

```
$result = $database->loadRowList();

foreach($result as $row)
    {
        $count++;
        if($count > 10000)
        {
            break;
        }
        ....
}
```

Массив 20000 эл, необходимо сперва перебрать 10000 эл массива, затем опять перебрать но уже след 10000, как мне выйти на начало перебора следующих 10тыс?

**Обновление**

Необходимо найти в базе дубли по артикулу, и вычислить есть ли в какой либо из групп дублей инфо, соотв, если есть, скопировать ее в в другую таблицу.

Запросом в базу возвращаю все дубликаты, затем схема незатейливая  На 1-ой стадии форичем раскидываю в один массив дубли в которых есть информация и другой массив без информации, далее форичем копирую инфо из одного массива в другой, затем опять же форичем проверяю есть ли в таблице существующая запись с айдишником дубликата который хочу записать, если нет, удаляю этот дубликат из массива, но и в конце записываю что осталось в таблицу. На этапе когда сравниваю массив с таблицей в базе все это не укладывается в сессию, хотел разбить на этапы

Answer (score 1):

Тут два варианта использовать limit в запросе `LIMIT 0,1000` и `LIMIT 1000,2000`. Это первый вариант. Ну и больше вариантов так как у вас грубо говоря один инстанс скрипта, и разницы небудет что 10 раз по 1000 переберать что 10000. Количество операций не измениться, а значит алгоритм будет эдентичен что в первом случае что во втором. Не думаю что есть необходимость перебора массива. Тут надо исходить из цели конечного результата. К примеру если надо убрать дубликат используйте `Distinct` в запросе и т.д.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.